# Convert Azure Function to Durable Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure function,

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(MyFunction) + "Trigger")]
    public async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
        ILogger log)
    {
         // Here the long running code
```

This Azure function is long running which might take couple of hours to finish. As per Azure function docs, the maximum timeout of consumption plan is 10 minutes.

So, do I need to convert this function into durable function to make it long run?

I tried,

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(MyFunction) + "Trigger")]
    public async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
        [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(MyFunction));
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(MyFunction))]
    public static async Task RunOrchestration(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext functionContext,
        ILogger log)
    {

         // Here the long running code
```

But this is not working, no errors but function is not executing. Am I missing something or the durable function should not be used used for this purpose?

So, in Azure what is the best way is to run long running code?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "just" use a Durable Function to get rid of run duration restrictions. I suggest you first take a look at the various, typical application patterns that Durable Function can solve: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#application-patterns

See if any of these fit your scenario (I could imagine the "Monitor" but its hard to judge without any context). Then pick the appropriate one and follow the examples how they are built. The main logic will always reside in "Activity" Fuctions, not the Orchestrator.

Comment: Look like Azure durable function also have this issue `Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded` https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2652

Comment: yes, Durable Functions does not mean "endlessly running function" ;)